# javascript prettify for mdx

Tags: mdx, javascript

I am looking for a JavaScript library like Google prettify (doesn't support MDX) to display MDX expressions in HTML so they can be displayed with color, indentation and line numbers.

Does anybody know such a library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a store procedure with the MDX script and then with web services and jscript you can add colors...etc.
Take a look at this [example](https://jesseorosz.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/calling-mdx-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/)